# Does your Pokemon evolve if you black out in the fight where it levels up?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

I have a Rufflet (bad choice so far) who is level 50 and I really want it to evolve to Braviary, so I gave it an Exp. Share and am grinding on the Elite 4.  I've spent all my money on various items and I don't care about using Return on any of my Pokemon, so I have little to lose from fainting them repeatedly.

My main concern is that I might black out in the battle where Rufflet finally gains his 54th level.  Would he still evolve to Braviary in this case?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After performing an experiment with a volunteer Pidgey, I can say: You will not get the chance to evolve Rufflet if you lose the battle.

**The experiment:**

1. Level 14 Pidgey, Level 100 Bronzong, Level 100 Heatran.
2. Lead with Pidgey vs. Level 71 Sharpedo.
3. Swap in Bronzong and explode.
4. Pidgey gains 17 levels.
5. Swap in Heatran Explode.
6. Swap in Pidgey and faint.
7. Rapida blacked out!
8. Wake up at the poke center.

*No Pokemon were harmed in the making of this experiment.*

Comment: Was this experiment performed in the 5th generation or earlier?  I noticed you used all pre-5th-generation pokemon.

Comment: It was done on Pokemon Black.

Comment: "No Pokemon were harmed in the making of this experiment."  Except the ones involved in the two explosions.  They're all dead.

Answer (score 2):

No, you will not.

**But**, if you level it one additional level and win that match successfully, your pokemon will evolve.

Answer (score 1):

> You will not get the chance to evolve Rufflet if you lose the battle.

If that happens, use a Rare Candy (if you have one) to give Rufflet an additional level. Rare Candies can evolve Pokemon, if they are at the correct level.